# AttributeError: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer_create'

Tags: python, opencv, attributeerror

I have google search all possible answers but none is working, I tried uninstalling opencv-contrib-python and installed back, I tried opencv-contrib-python --upgrade but all condition was met, and I tried runing the code over and over buy keeps showing thesame error.

```
import cv2
from time import sleep
from PIL import Image 

def main_app(name):
        
        face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('./data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()   
        recognizer.read(f"./data/classifiers/{name}_classifier.xml")
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        pred = 0
        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            #default_img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
```

Comment: Try this in the terminal `pip install opencv-contrib-python --user` and then execute `cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()`.